# You are using a GPT bootdisk on a non efi system

Tags: centos

While installing CentOS on "HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 Server"

(Server have 2TB*6 Disks. with 4 Disks in RAID 5 and 2 Spares Giving me total of 5.5 TB)

I am facing this warning while installation.

> "you are using a GPT bootdisk on a non efi system. This May not work.
>   Depending upon your BIOS........ (some long messge)"

and after install completes the System is not booting...

i have this partition Table

```
/ 6GB
/home 1TB
/usr 80 GB
/opt 80GB
/var 300 GB
SWAP 128 GB
/xmldata 1TB
/mysqldata 3 TB
```

Please advise.

Thanks
Ali

Answer (score 0):

Convert the disk from GPT to MBR.
You can use a Linux live CD to boot, use gparted (or install it from EPEL if you're using CentOS), and convert it to MBR.
Also, I assumed no MS windows OS in installed on the disk. It gets a bit trickier if you want to have dual boot.

Comment: MBR doesn't support drives larger than 2TB.

Comment: Yes, but he has 6 disks of 2TB. He converts only one of the disks from GPT to MBR. Rest he can mount them.

Comment: I guess you missed that the disks are in a single 5.5 TB RAID so installing on one disk is not an option.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, my idea was to convert one of the spare disks to MBR, and mount the raid, and one extra disk. Also, 4 disks of 2TB in Raid5 + 2 * 2TB = 6TB+4TB isn't it? ( I'm only using my theoretical knowledge.)